# Folding with anonymous functions

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions, folding

I'm currently trying to learn folding.

But instead of using predefined functions I want to use my own.

So I want to double all vowels in a String.

```
doubleVowels :: String -> String
```

My attempt is (yet just for 'a', as I'm try solve it for one letter first and will expand and optimize it, once it runs):

```
doubleVowels :: String -> String
doubleVowels  a = foldl (\eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a) "" a
```

Trying to run he code I'm getting the following erorr:

```
Experimenting.hs:8:78: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char -> Char'
      Expected type: Char -> Char
        Actual type: String
    * In the expression: a
      In the expression: if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a
      In the first argument of `foldl', namely
        `(\ eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a)'
  |
8 | doubleVowels a = foldl (\eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a) "" a
  |                                                                              ^

Experimenting.hs:8:81: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the second argument of `foldl', namely `""'
      In the expression:
        foldl
          (\ eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a) "" a
      In an equation for `doubleVowels':
          doubleVowels
            = foldl
                (\ eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a) "" a
  |
8 | doubleVowels a = foldl (\eachChar -> if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a) "" a
  |                                                                                 ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```hs
doubleVowels :: String -> String
doubleVowels  a = foldr (\eachChar b -> if eachChar == 'a' then ("aa" ++ b) else (eachChar:b)) "" a
```

In most cases, if there is no specific reason for `foldl`, use [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) instead of `foldl` as it allows the Haskell compiler to lazily evaluate your expression. If I remember correctly, even then use `foldl'`, since `foldl` is not strict and takes too much memory while not giving you any benefit for the laziness.

Apart from that, you are missing the second argument to `foldr`s (or `foldl`s) function. `foldr` has type:

```hs
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

The function to `foldr` has type `a -> b -> b` where the first argument is the current element of the folding structure and the second is the accumulator. The lambda that you are using has only one parameter.

In addition, the body of the lambda function also doesn't make much sense.

```hs
if eachChar == 'a' then (a ++ "aa") else a)
```

`a` is the parameter that the surrounding function `doubleVowels` receives. You need to use the parameters of the lambda function here.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the function used in `foldl` should have two argments. The first one is the accmulated result, and the other is current char.
Second, the order of evaluation of foldl is from left to right, so we have to `reverse` the result string.

For example, here is a modified version

```
 doubleVowels :: String -> String
 doubleVowels s = reverse $ foldl (\x y -> if y == 'a' then ("aa" ++ x) else (y : x)) "" s
```